# unexpected unindent even after using except and try properly

Tags: python

Unexpected unident

```
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)
            results = mod.fit()
print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: What's up with that `print`?

Comment: Your `print` line needs to have the same indent as the line above it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `print` with the same indent with commands of `try:`

Ex:

```py
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)
            results = mod.fit()
            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation represents block of code. Using indentation, Python will make decisions. In your question, print statement belongs to which block? try block or except block? How Python makes decision? So it is throwing error. To fix this, print statement should have same indentation as other statements in try block as shown in the below code.

```
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)
            results = mod.fit()
            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        except:
            continue
```